# Copy Database taking too long to create because of BLOB

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to create a copy database.  Please see the query below:

```
SELECT CaptureDate, GenieVRMs.VRM, Camera, ShortName, Latitude, Longitude, ImageBlob, WeedDate, OverviewWeedDate, LastUpdated 
FROM (select * from openquery (bof2, 'SELECT CaptureDate, Bof2PlateImage.VRM, Camera, ShortName, Latitude, Longitude, Bof2PlateImage.WeedDate, ''1900-01-01'' AS OverviewWeedDate, 
''1900-01-01'' LastUpdated FROM bof2.Bof2PlateImage  inner join BOF2.CAMERA on BOF2.Bof2PlateImage.CAMERA = BOF2.CAMERA.URN where rownum<1000000')) As BOF INNER JOIN GenieVRMs 
ON BOF.VRM=GenieVRMs.VRM
```

There are 70451258 rows.  I have transferred 1,000,000 records using SSIS i.e. the above is an OLEDB source command (Oracle database) and the destination is an SQL database.  I have worked out that it will take about two months to transfer the 60,000,000 rows.  I have tried the following TSQL query:

```
select * into CopyDatabase(
SELECT CaptureDate, GenieVRMs.VRM, Camera, ShortName, Latitude, Longitude, ImageBlob, WeedDate, OverviewWeedDate, LastUpdated 
FROM (select * from openquery (bof2, 'SELECT CaptureDate, Bof2PlateImage.VRM, Camera, ShortName, Latitude, Longitude, ImageBlob, Bof2PlateImage.WeedDate, ''1900-01-01'' AS OverviewWeedDate, 
''1900-01-01'' LastUpdated FROM bof2.Bof2PlateImage  inner join BOF2.CAMERA on BOF2.Bof2PlateImage.CAMERA = BOF2.CAMERA.URN where rownum<1000000')) As BOF INNER JOIN GenieVRMs 
ON BOF.VRM=GenieVRMs.VRM 
) as CopyDatabase
```

Again the results suggest it will take two months to create the copy database.

I believe this is due to the images (ImageBlob).  Is there anything I can do to compress the images on data transfer?

Comment: if the images are in jpg it will be difficult to compress them. you need export all the images to external files, export the tables, copy images and import them separatetly

Comment: @are, thanks. I have not tried this. How would it be faster?

Answer (score 0):

you need try to use BULK operations

```
INSERT ... SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...)
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx

Bulk Import Large-Object Data by using the OPENROWSET Bulk Rowset Provider (SQL Server):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176001.aspx

but I would to following steps

1. export all data except BLOBS from oracle into CSV file
   additionally generate unique ID for each image
2. import the file to MSSQL using BULK insert tools
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx
3. BLOB data - export to drive as image files, using the unique ID that was generated on 1st step as file name
4. import the files into database separately (or! depends on logic of the project maybe it would be easy keep them separately in image storage but in database just keep link to the files)